# Add tooltip in button control orderlist Primeng

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tooltip, primeng

I try to add tooltip in controls button orderlist

**My Component**

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-block',
  templateUrl: './block.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./block.component.css'],
  styles:[`
    button[icon="pi pi-angle-double-up"] {
      /* what should I write here */
    }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

So is there any other way to add a tooltip to the button I want or what is the correct way to do this with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is to customize your block.component.html and block.component.css like that :

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">

  <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```